# How can I add stroke thickness to x3dom LineSet

Tags: x3dom

I'm trying to add a stroke thickness to a x3dom indexedLineSet. All I could find so far is the [x3dom LineProperty](https://doc.x3dom.org/author/Shape/LineProperties.html). But the proposed linewidthScaleFactor seems to have no effect.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```html
<shape render="true" bboxcenter="0,0,0" bboxsize="-1,-1,-1" ispickable="true">
  <lineset vertexcount="5" solid="true" ccw="true" usegeocache="true" lit="true">
    <coordinate point="-0.5 0.5 0, 0.5 0.5 0, 0.5 -0.5 0, -0.5 -0.5 0, -0.5 0.5 0"></coordinate>
  </lineset>
  <appearance sorttype="auto" alphaclipthreshold="0.1">
    <material emissivecolor="1 1 0" ambientintensity="0.2" diffusecolor="0.8,0.8,0.8" shininess="0.2" specularcolor="0,0,0">
      <lineproperties linewidthscalefactor="3" applied="true" linetype="1"></lineproperties>
    </material>
   </appearance>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code snippet is correct. The problem is the browser. In my case chrome does not handle the `WebGL lineWidth` correct. [[Issue Demo](http://alteredqualia.com/tmp/webgl-linewidth-test/)]